# avconf or winff

Tags: video, ffmpeg, winff

My simple question is: What should I do with the hint:

*** THIS PROGRAM IS DEPRECATED ***
This program is only provided for compatibility and will be removed in a future release. Please use avconv instead.

which can be seen in the terminal every time when you start winff?

I like winff because it works very well, but the message is confusing, even if I see this message for years.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv/9477756#9477756), and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/507386/libav-vs-ffmpeg-better-to-use-libav-avconv-today) for some detailed explanation on the history of the project and the potentially misleading warning. [This answer](http://superuser.com/questions/507386/libav-vs-ffmpeg-better-to-use-libav-avconv-today) is particularly informative.

Comment: Also see [The FFmpeg/Libav situation](http://blog.pkh.me/p/13-the-ffmpeg-libav-situation.html).